# apache mod rewrite with the_request

Tags: mod-rewrite

I want to do the following with apache (mod rewrite).

1. if the user requests http://hostname.tld/index.php/folder/subfolder i want it to redirect (with a R=301) to http://hostname.tld/folder/subfolder.
2. if the user requests http://hostname.tld/folder/subfolder the request should internally be rewritten to index.php/folder/subfolder.

To prevent an endless redirect the first rule should check for %{THE_REQUEST}. The problem here is that I am unable to append "folder/subfolder" with a regex. How should I do this?

For the second rule I have this (and seems to work).

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} hostname.tld [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

The first one is still a problem.

I think the first one should be something like

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} (.*)index.php(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule /index.php/$ http://hostname.tld/$1 [R=301,QSA,L]
```

But that is not really it.

Answer (score 0):

The first should be.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^hostname\.tld$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^index.php/(.*)$ http://hostname.tld/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I also see that your second rule redirects  `http://hostname.tld/folder/subfolder` to  `http://hostname.tld/index.php` (not `http://hostname.tld/index.php/folder/subfolder`). But as long as that works it's fine, as this it also prevents the redirect loop.
 But just in case, here is the solution to add the folder/subfolder part:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^hostname\.tld$ [NC]
RewriteCond $1 !^index\.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,L]
```